# Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: error only in WAS but not in spring embedded tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websphere

I am getting the below exception in WAS 9 although the same code in STS is working fine

I am using spring boot 2 & I have been trying for hours to find the reason for this issue, this problem happens when this line of code is called:

```
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

String token = jwtTokenProvider.resolveToken((HttpServletRequest) req);
try {
    logger.debug("we entered the doFilter of the JwtTokenFilter");
    if (token != null && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token)) {

        logger.debug("before the getAuthentication");
      Authentication auth = token != null ? jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(token) : null;
```

The `getAuthentication` method is as follows & the return type is of `org.springframework.security.core.Authentication`:

```
  public Authentication getAuthentication(String token) {

    String userID = getUserID(token);

    List<Role> role = new ArrayList<Role>();
    role.add(Role.ROLE_CLIENT);
    logger.debug("we are in the getAuthentication method");

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken userAuthToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userID, "", role);

    logger.debug("userAuthToken is"+ userAuthToken.toString());

    return userAuthToken;

  }
```

The exception in WAS 9 is as follows:

```
""2018-10-29 17:11:42 [WebContainer : 9] ERROR c.e.s.c.ExceptionHandlingController invalidInput 45 - Unknown error 
"org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.initialize(Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;)V
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1235)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:143)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at com.ejada.staripo.security.JwtTokenFilter.doFilter(JwtTokenFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:969)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1109)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:82)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:963)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:382)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:318)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.initialize(Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;)V
    at org.apache.bval.jsr.ConstraintValidation.validateGroupContext(ConstraintValidation.java:161)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr.ConstraintValidation.validate(ConstraintValidation.java:145)
    at org.apache.bval.util.ValidationHelper.validateProperty(ValidationHelper.java:236)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr.ClassValidator.validateBean(ClassValidator.java:460)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr.ClassValidator.validateBeanNet(ClassValidator.java:406)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr.ClassValidator.validateBeanWithGroups(ClassValidator.java:152)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr.ClassValidator.validate(ClassValidator.java:139)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidatorAdapter.validate(ValidatorAdapter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:871)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.validateIfApplicable(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:260)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    ... 92 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the reason for this, this exception in WAS happens only if I check this checkbox shown below **(metadata-complete-attribute)** during application installation, I am not very sure of the reason but unchecking this option makes the application work as expected **(metadata-complete-attribute)**

Any justification for why this happens is welcome.

Edit:

As per this [link from IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.iseries.doc/ae/urun_rapp_metadata_lockdd.html), there is some helpful description justifying when not to set this attribute as true:

> Avoid trouble
>
> **If your Java EE 5 or later application uses annotations and a shared
>   library, do not select metadata-complete attribute**. When your
>   application uses annotations and a shared library, setting the
>   metadata-complete attribute to true causes the product to incorrectly
>   represent an @EJB annotation in the deployment descriptor as 
>   rather than . For web modules, setting the
>   metadata-complete attribute to true might cause InjectionException
>   errors. If you must select metadata-complete attribute (set the
>   metadata-complete attribute to true), avoid errors by not using a
>   shared library, by placing the shared library in either the classes or
>   lib directory of the application server, or by fully specifying the
>   metadata in the deployment descriptors.

[image]